# Objective-c: asl_log alternatives

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to implement [GTMLogger](https://github.com/codinn/GTMLogger)
But I'm getting deprecated API in the following lines:

```
client_ = asl_open(NULL, [facility UTF8String], 0);
if (client_ != NULL) asl_close(client_);
asl_log(client_, NULL, level, "%s", [msg UTF8String]);
```

All the regarding asl. Any of you knows and asl or how to get to work GTMLogger ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it failing or just giving warnings?

Comment: @PhillipMills, warnings

Comment: is there solution for deprecated asl_log?